# Attachment File using REST was failed to upload with the problem of SP.RequestExecutor.js

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

How can I add attachment in SharePoint I am stuck on this problem hopefully can help me to proceed this problem. I will so much appreciate your help. Thank you.

[image: This is the console on the browser]

[image: This is the sample screenshot of my custom script]

Comment: Is it SharePoint hosted App or something else

Comment: Yes it is hosted app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used **SP.RequestExecutor** which is used for making cross domain calls and if so your **_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl** won't work.
Either you need to  use query string to get the url or try using hard code url value.
For getting url from  query string

```
hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );
appweburl =
           decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
        );

var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
```

For reference [Click here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/access-sharepoint-data-from-add-ins-using-the-cross-domain-library)

Comment: Could you please send me the link of the main function on how can I attach file in sharepoint using custom.

Comment: You can refer here
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the error your encountering , I believe you want to change your call to `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl` to `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`

The following article provides a good breakdown on the properties available on `_spPageContextInfo`

https://sympmarc.com/2013/03/26/using-_sppagecontextinfo-to-determine-the-current-sharepoint-context-in-script/

Comment: Please specify the function of attachment or the problem on my code.